# Analysing &, && and | for this code?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, mips, nios, bit-masks

I want to illustrate the difference with this code

```
for(i = 32; i > 0; i--)
 {
   if(a&1 != 0) //bit mask
     total += b;
   a = a >> 1;
   b = b << 1; 
 }
```

In the code & is used to "mask" a bit and the result would have been completely different if `&&` had been used instead. In that case the expression `1` had been interpreted as a truth value (`TRUE`) instead of a one-bit position that is used to keep one of the bits. Correct? But what would instead happen if I did like this:

```
for(i = 32; i > 0; i--)
 {
   if(a|1 != 0) //bit mask
     total += b;
   a = a >> 1;
   b = b << 1; 
 }
```

In the first case the `1` is used to keep only the LSB (least significant bit) i.e. rightmost bit and nothing else. What would `|`do in its place? What would be the difference if I did this change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a&1 != 0
```

should be

```
(a&1) != 0
```

`!=` has higher precedence than `&`.  Otherwise  `a&1 != 0` is read as `a & (1 != 0)`.

Same for `(a|1 != 0)`.

Comment: That's very interesting since these are taken from course notes in computer engineering where the code should be correct. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz This is a very common mistake. This precedence is counter-intuitive because it is an historical bad design choice made by D. Ritchie. See here for more info: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

Answer (score 1):

```
(a | 1 ) != 0
```

Is true always.  It has the effect of returning a but with the lowest bit set which is clearly not 0 (at least not in any C implementation I have ever seen).  Similarly

```
(a || 1)
```

is always true, since 1 is true in C and anything or true is true.

Answer (score 1):

In this very instance, your omission of braces around `a&1` does not change the meaning of the program.

Since `!=` has precedence, it will evaluate `1 != 0` which is `1` and since `!=0` is an utterly redundant statement, it doesn't matter whether you say `if (a OP (1 != 0))` or `if ((a OP 1) != 0)`.

Now, we can look at your second statement and interpret it as you intended: `(a | 1) != 0`. The only value where all bits are zero is `0` which is on the right of the comparison but on the left side you always have a value with at least one bit set (the rightmost). Thus these will in fact *never* be equal, thus `(a | 1) != 0` is the same as `1`.

So, the difference is that `(a & 1)` actually checks if `a` is odd and increments `total` only then, while `(a | 1)` increments `total` in each iteration as the condition is a tautology.